# C function with variable number of arguments returns unexpected output when called with fewer number of arguments

Tags: c, for-loop, parameters, variadic-functions

I'm learning C, and I created a simple `addNumbers(int num, ...)` function, that takes any number of int arguments, and returns the sum of them.

This issue is that when I get the output of `addNumbers(4, 2)`, the output is `14823901`. Which is obviously incorrect.

When I call the function `addNumbers(4, 2, 4, 7, 10)`, it outputs `23`, which is also incorrect because it should be `27`, but at least it's closer.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

// Functions with variable number of arguments
int addNumbers(int num, ...)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    // List to hold variable amount of parameters
    va_list parameters;

    // Initialize "parameters" list with arguments
    va_start(parameters, num);

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        // Adds each "int" argument from "parameters" to sum
        sum += va_arg(parameters, int);
    }

    // Cleans memory
    va_end(parameters);

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i", addNumbers(4, 2, 4, 7, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

Should I not be using `va_list`, `va_arg`, etc...?

What's the best way to be able to take in a variable number of arguments?

Comment: Why is this tagged with c++?

Comment: C++ offers other solutions, notably parameter packs.

Comment: 1) "_When I call the function `addNumbers(4, 2, 4, 7, 10)`, it outputs `23`, which is also incorrect because it should be `27`_" What? `2 + 4 + 7 + 10 = 23`. Why should the answer be `27`? 2) "_This issue is that when I get the output of `addNumbers(4, 2)`, the output is `14823901`._" Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: You are using the first parameter as the count of numbers to add, but that's not the result you seem to be expecting.

Comment: `addNumbers(4, 2)` since you use the first number as argument to `va_start` you end up "lying" to the function about how many arguments you passed in. So then your loop tries to access values that don't exist, which is *undefined behavior*

Comment: Another word for "undefined behavior" is "bug"

Comment: ok thanks for the input guys, I had no idea that meant "undefined" in C (still learning).
I'll go back and read the documentation for the va_start stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Did you create this `addNumbers` function, or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: Understanding your own function parameters woud be the first step. Rename `num` into `nr_of_addends` and all will be more clear. The way _you_ use of va_list/va_args seems ok.

Comment: The _first_ argument to `addNumbers` is the count/number of arguments that follow. That is, if the first arg is `3`, you need 3 _more_ arguments (e.g): `addNumbers(3,5,6,7);` If you use `5`, you need 5 more (e.g.): `addNumbers(5,1,2,3,4,5);` If you provide _fewer_ extra arguments (e.g.): `addNumbers(4,2);`, you'll get random/UB results because the function will continue beyond what you provided [pulling semi-random values from whatever happens to be on the stack at those locations].

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes I created it.

Got it working now, figured out the 1st number is the number of arguments thanks to you guys

Comment: @ESM: I am puzzled how you could have created the routine and not been aware of the purpose of `num`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for addNumber(4, 2) you are using the first parameter as counter which there are 4 parameter to addup but your giving just 1, so the for loop continue reading from the memory expecting more parameter and just pick up ramdom values and add them up.